# An effective coding of $\mathbb N^*$

Tags: computability, recursion

**Problem:**
Assume $\Pi:\mathbb N^2\to\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$ is a primitive recursive coding of the pairs of numbers, that is also a bijection and $(\forall (x,y)\in\mathbb N^2)(\Pi(x,y)>max(x,y))$.

Let $\mathbb N^*$ be the words on the alphabet of natural numbers and $\epsilon$ be the empty word. Let

$$k:\mathbb N^*\to\mathbb N:$$
$$k(\epsilon)=0$$
$$k(\langle x_1\dots x_n\rangle)=\Pi(x_1,k(\langle x_2\dots x_n\rangle)$$

Show that $k$ is an effective coding of $\mathbb N^*$

**Some thoughts:** I need to show that $k$ is a bijection and that its length and member functions are primitive recursive. I can show that $k$ is injective on my own. How can I show that $k$ is surjective? I tried using course-by-values induction on the length of the word but failed. Additionally, how can I show that the length function is primitive recursive? Having the above, I can show that the member functions are primitive recursive.

**p.s.** This is part of the problem only. I am working with a given $\Pi$, that I have show to be a primitive recursive coding. Moreover, using that $k$ is an effective coding I have shown that a bunch of other functions are primitive recursive. To avoid a long post, however, I have left out those details.

Comment: I think you need slightly more than what you've given so far: firstly, you need $\Pi$ to be a bijection or trivially $k$ can't be.  Secondly, you need to code $n$ into $k$; otherwise there's no way of uniquely 'unwinding' the coding (for instance, suppose that $\Pi(3,5) = 8$; then there's no way of disambiguating $k(\langle 2, 3, 5\rangle)$ from $k(\langle 2, 8\rangle)$.

Comment: Also, if you choose the right $\Pi$ (e.g., one with $\Pi(m,n)\geq \max(m, n)$ for all $m,n$) then you have that $k(\langle x_1, \ldots, x_n\rangle)\geq n$ trivially, so given a value of $k$ you can determine an easy bound on the maximum length of the sequence $\langle\vec{x}\rangle$, which should be all you need for primitive recursively here.

Comment: I am working with $\Pi(x,y)=2^x(2y+1)$, yet I feel like I've shown $k$ to be injective, thus the code unwinds uniquely. I'll be glad if you can show the contrary, @Steven.

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you're saying - I had missed the point that $k(\langle x_1, x_2\rangle) \neq \Pi(x_1, x_2)$.  I believe you're correct, yes; you 'have to' keep decoding until you reach a zero.  Note that this coding does satisfy the condition in my second comment, so you have the bound on sequence length given by the number being decoded.

Comment: I am having major doubts that your $k$ is injective.  But I am also not entirely certain how $k$ acts on $1$-tuples.

Comment: $k(<x>)=\Pi(x,k(\epsilon))=\Pi(x,0)=2^x$ @ArthurFischer

Comment: Thanks, @Ivan. I was being somewhat dense. It is surely bijective. I'm not sure exactly how to show that the "uncoding" functions are primitive recursive, but you can show that $k(\langle x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\rangle)=2^{x_1}\color{red}{(}2^{x_2+1} \color{blue}{(}\cdots (2^{x_n+1}+1)\cdots \color{blue}{)}+1\color{red}{)}$. The idea of decoding numbers to sequences is clear. The first coordinate is the largest $x$ such that $2^x$ dividing your number. The second coordinate is the largest $y$ such that $2^y$ divides $k_1 = ((k/2^x)-1)/2$. And similarly for the remaining coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumptions in the question is not enough for your $k$ to work.

For example if $\Pi(x,y)=\frac{(x+y)(x+y+1)}2+x$ (the Cantor zig-zag, a fairly standard choice of pairing function), then $\Pi(0,0)=0$ and hence
$$ k(\langle \rangle) = 0 = k(\langle 0 \rangle) = k(\langle0,0\rangle) = \cdots$$

You need the additional assumption that the range of $\Pi$ is exactly $\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$ (as is the case for the $\Pi$ you give in the comments) -- then $k$ will a bijection.